# django-guardian example source code

Tags: django, permissions, user-permissions, database-permissions, django-permissions

Can anyone suggest a good open source app that uses django-guardian?  I'm not having trouble understanding the API, but I'd love to see an example to get a feel for implementation best practice (database design, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If you clone the [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) source code you have a working example of how to use it.
And in this [link](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian/blob/master/docs/userguide/admin-integration.rst) are the instructions for integrating it with django admin

Comment: This is an old answer so it might have become irrelevant now. But where do I look in the source? There's barely a few lines in example_project/models.py

Answer (score 1):

Django userena uses Django-guardian: https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena