# Django Models and Permission Restrictions

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Models:

`Company`

`Product`

We have a parent company (owner of all) who can create any `Company` and any `Product`, as sub-Company or sub-Product.

Now, what I'd like to accomplish, is limiting which Company can CRUD other Companies and Products alike.

Here's are the scenarios:

Company and Sub-Companies (sub-contractors):

```
Master (creates) -> Company “A”
Master (creates) -> Company “B” (creates) -> Company “C”
Master (creates) -> Company “D” (creates) -> Company “F” (creates) -> Company “G”
```

Company and Product Assignment:

```
Master (Add Product) -> Show all products
Master (assign products to top levels) -> Company “A”, Company “B” and Company ”D”
```

Sub-Company Product Assignment (management):

```
Company “B” (assign products only to sub-level) -> Company “C”
Company “D” (assign products only to sub-level) -> Company “F”
Company “F” (assign products only to sub-level) -> Company “G”
```

However, if `Company D` removes a product from a sub-level, this will also remove from all sub-level products recursively.

Are there any sure ways of doing this with Django core, or perhaps there's a recommended library out there that I'm not finding? I also saw in the Django docs reference to `Model Meta options` and the `Options.permissions` method... but I'm not sure that's what I'm needing either.

Comment: Permissions are generally related to (logged in) users. Does each user belong to a company?

Comment: Yes, each user belongs to a company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Company(models.Model)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')


Company.objects.get(pk=1).children.all()
```

The rest of the logic I can control through `Views`

Answer (score 5):

The best package I can suggest you is [DJANGO GUARDIAN](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian). But what you are really looking for `Role Based Access Control Logic`.

Unfortunately django-guardian doesn't support roles. [Linked issue](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/issues/23). So I suggest you write your own views for that. But you can look into these below packages:

- [django-role-permissions](https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-role-permissions)
- [django-rbac](https://bitbucket.org/nabucosound/django-rbac)
- [django-group-access](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-group-access/1.1.17)
- [django-teamwork](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-teamwork/0.2.0)

Comment: Thanks for this, do you know of any examples out there using Guardian that I could dissect?

Comment: [DOCS](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/example_project.html) are always the best sources. But since you asked, check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794566/django-guardian-example-source-code) question as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few general ways to manage access, including ownership/role and object specific permissions.

Ownership is what [Django Organizations](https://github.com/bennylope/django-organizations) uses as the out-of-the-box permission management strategy. An object is *owned* by an organization - and only one - and access is limited to members (role) of that organization. You can expand on this as you like in a Django Organizations-based application, but you don't most of the benefits.

Instead, it *sounds like* you need a hierarchal solution to manage access to objects (companies or products) that do not necessarily have a primary relationship to one specific company. That is, an admin at the top level may choose to associate a product with one or more child companies, and removing an association would recursively remove that object's associations further down the tree.

So it does sound like you should take a look at either [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) or [django-treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard) to record a tree of the company and product relationships, using the tree as the source of truth for access in views, and ensuring that all child relationships are removed when a product is removed from one company.

I'd stress that this *sounds like* part because it's not totally clear if that is exactly what you're trying to solve for and if that's all that you need to solve for.

Comment: Also, are you suggesting that `django-mptt` would be used in conjunction with `django-organizations`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a base view that checks which company the user belongs to.   Each (inherited) view will restrict the functionality depending on the logged in user's company.  Use [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/) for dealing with tree structured data.